# has_many through invisible validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, has-many-through, has-many, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a setup where I want to be able to build a role record to point to a users skills, venues, productions, groups and so on.

I set it up as a has many through relationship with everything going though roles and roles belonging to everything as so:

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :skill
  belongs_to :production
  belongs_to :venue
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :group
end
```

and set the individual role categories as so:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users, through: :roles
end
```

All are the same, except for users, which of course has lots of detail to the model.

Every table has a name field, and an id field, and the standard timestamp fields.

I set it up to index on the names for each table.

When I try to build a role as record with just a role_id, user_id, and skill_id I get back errors in the console saying I need values for everything.

Does this mean I have to build a has_many through relationship for each type of role with it's own "through"? Or can one has_many through table work in the fashion I envision? And why is it trying to validate the presence of data for each field? Would it be due to indexing?

If i wanted to turn that validation off I'm not even sure where to put the code, as I'm not sure where the validation comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour of Rails 5 belongs_to is that the parent association must be present, so yes, you would need all the fields in order to save a role.

However, to turn off this behaviour, change to:

```
# config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb
Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = false
# this would disable this configuration for the entire application
```

**UPDATE**

Another approach would be to figure out the most important associations and ensure those are available and the set an optional tag on the optional associations, like so:

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :skill, optional: true # assume skill & production are optional
  belongs_to :production, optional: true
  belongs_to :venue
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :group
end
```

Comment: it won't let me upvote you because I'm a dirty NOOB,  but thanks!

followup: should I be modeling this in a different fashion?

Comment: Updated the answer to add the optional flag. I think that may be a better approach

Comment: If you can't upvote, you can accept the answer if it solves your problem

Comment: Thanks again. I had no idea that check mark was clickable. Updated answer is perfect!